# Get the unique thread ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, logging

I need to write the actual user thread ID to a log file. If I use `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` I don't get the unique ID, but the same one over and over again.

The reason is to track `log.Info` for user across the system, and later if I see a problem, I'll be able to search in the log `WHERE threadId = ?` and get the entire activity flow from the log.

I don't mind getting it inside the code of log4net.

I am talking about the server thread and not manual thread.

Comment: `ManagedThreadId` is meant to be unique across managed threads. Are you sure you are not using reusable threads from thread pool?

Comment: @Vlad, thanks, as I written above, these are not manual threads, I am talking about ASP.NET auto threads

Comment: Well, you're finding out how asp.net works, it is actually the same thread handling multiple requests.  You'll need to look for something else to log.  Something session related perhaps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is NOT possible because your threads in ASP.NET/IIS are running on the thread pool of IIS... it is not even guaranteed that a HTTP request runs completely on the same thread (for example if there is some I/O operation it could "go sleep" and get reassigned to another thread from the pool)...

What exactly is the goal ? Perhaps there is some other way to achieve that...

**EDIT - as per comments:**

To track a request you could try logging the hash code of that request (accessible via [`GetHashCode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx)) and/or log a hash of a combination of the values of some of the properties/fields of the http request object...

IF you dig deeper you could get your hands on a worker request object which has a (request specific) `TraceID` property...

if you want to track the session that entirely depends on your session management (be it a hidden html form field and/or a cookie and/or user and/or something else...).

Comment: Hi - that is not really clear to me, do you want to track one http request OR a whole session ?

Comment: If you can provide an example of how to get both it would be grate, if not, what ever you can, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your original assumption is inaccurate: the "actual thread" is reused again and again, which is why you're getting the same thread ID again and again.

Your mistake is to assume that each request will be handled by a separate thread. `ManagedThreadId` is working fine.

Now let's look at what you're trying to do:

> The reason is to track log.Info for user across the system

So you want to track the interactions with a *user*. Not a thread, a *user*. The same user may have interactions on multiple threads, and multiple users may use the same thread... so what you want to log is the *user* ID, not the thread ID.

Comment: Thanks, So understand what is the problem with my assumption, How do I track the HTTP request or the Session? thanks

Comment: @SexyMF: Why not log the user ID? Note that even within a single request, thread agility means that different bits of the same request can be handled on different threads.

Comment: @SexyMF: Ah, in the title, yes. It's useful to put it in the tags and body text, rather than the title. I'll edit out that bit though...

Comment: OK, the user does not actually logging in, so there is no session, maybe i can track the http request, can you provide an example?

Comment: @SexyMF: You could give each session a unique ID yourself - I don't know whether anything is provided automatically in the framework though.